# Ionic released app is very slow and so much delay (Only slow on device)

Tags: android, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

hi when test my app in ionic lab very good but when create apk file and install to device very slow. delay for click on button
delay to push page
delay to open modal
close modal,

delay for anything

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your app in development mode it takes some time to fire the platform.ready() event since it has assertions and various necessary framework checks turned on.

Try running the app in production mode to speed up and optimize the start of your application

If you're in an ionic 2 app, you can enable this by doing the following,

open **src/app/main.ts**

```
Import enableProdMode from Angular 2 core

import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
```

Then call the enableProdMode() function before bootstraping your module

```
enableProdMode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and now while running the app through cli try adding a flag like "--prod"

ionic run android --prod
In ionic 3.x, you don't have to enable anything in the code. you can simply run it using the cli command,

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

Hope that helps

Comment: i use enableProdMode() in main.ts
you say me not use platform.ready()??